# PHP Laravel, Replacement for method updateOrCreate

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

The following problem is part of bigger project. As a junior I got task to replace Laravel's method updaterOrCreate which is used to creating token. Used method is:

```
public function creaOUp(
    string $token,
    string $carId,
    int $exDate,
    string $log,
    int $driverId
): DriverToken {
    $token = DriverToken::onWriteConnection()->updateOrCreate([
        'car_id' => $carId,
        'driver_id' => $driverId
    ], [
        'token' => $token,
        'ex_date' => $exDate,
        'login' => $log,
    ]);

    return $token;
}
```

Method is called in project like this:

```
private $driverTokenRepository;
//....
        return $this->driverTokenRepository->creaOUp(
            (string)$jwt,
            $deviceData->uid,
            $jwt->getClaim('exp'),
            $claims->getLogin(),
            $claims->getDriverParentId()
  //....
```

Method which I've replaced method updateOrCreate:

```
 public function creaOUp(
    string $token,
    string $carId,
    int $exDate,
    string $log,
    int $driverId
): DriverToken {
    $token = DriverToken::query()
    ->where([
        'car_id' => $carId,
        'driver_id' => $driverId,
    ])
    ->first();
    
    if ($token !== null) {
        $token->update([
                 'token' => $token,
                 'car_id' => $carId,
                 'ex_date' => $exDate,
                 'login' => $log, 
                 
             ]);
    } else {
        $token = DriverToken::create([
            'token' => $token,
            'car_id' => $carId,
            'ex_date' => $exDate,
            'login' => $log,
            'driver_id' => $driverId,
        ]);
    }

    return $token;
}
```

I was sure that it will work, however I've got error:

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'token' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `driver_tokens` (`token`, `car_id`, `ex_date`, `login`, `driver_id`) values (?, cba567D1, 2425452525, HUGO_315, 3))"
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why token is null? With orginal Laravel's updateOrCreate it worked, maybe I really don't understand this method?

Comment: the error message clearly specify that you can not set null value in token field and even it gives you the table name. so you just need to check why that token value is going null or set that field as a nullable in the database table.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But the only thing I've changed was replacement from updateOrCreate with my own method, which should work the same way. Question is what is wrong with method creaOUp.

Comment: can you try $this->token the place where you query the token and also you pass it as a prams?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

First of all, thanks sandy for trying help, it was my first post on StackOverflow :D

The issue was with param $token. It was used as literally token and also as query. I've just changed $token in query as:

```
    public function creaOUp(
    string $token,
    string $carId,
    int $exDate,
    string $log,
    int $driverId
): DriverToken {
    $quer = DriverToken::query()
    ->where([
        'car_id' => $carId,
        'driver_id' => $driverId,
    ])
    ->first();
    
    if ($quer !== null) {
        $quer->update([
                 'token' => $token,
                 'car_id' => $carId,
                 'ex_date' => $exDate,
                 'login' => $log, 
                 
             ]);
    } else {
        $quer = DriverToken::create([
            'token' => $token,
            'car_id' => $carId,
            'ex_date' => $exDate,
            'login' => $log,
            'driver_id' => $driverId,
        ]);
    }

    return $quer;
}
```

It solved the problem. :)